# How to tell which table column is causing an invalid cast exception?

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

Using EF Core 3.1, I'm trying to get a table from the database (SQL Server) using the following code:

```
query = dbContext.Set<Entity>().ToList();
```

The code is working for other tables but fails on a specific table with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.Int32'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Using a breakpoint in a try-catch doesn't help as the inner exception is null. How can I tell which table column is causing the cast exception?

Model code:

```
[Table("Plugin")]
public partial class Plugin
{
public Plugin()
{
    SetAPlugins = new HashSet<SetProfile>();
    SetBplugins = new HashSet<SetProfile>();
    SetBPlugins = new HashSet<SetProfile>();
    SetBPlugins = new HashSet<SetProfile>();
    SetBPlugins = new HashSet<SetProfile>();
}   

[Key]
[Column("ID")]
public Guid ID { get; set; }
public int Serial { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
public ObjectStatus ObjectStatus { get; set; }
[Required]
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
public PluginType Type { get; set; }
[StringLength(64)]
public string Name { get; set; }
[StringLength(512)]
public string ProcessorAssembly { get; set; }
[StringLength(512)]
public string ProcessorClass { get; set; }
[StringLength(512)]
public string AdminAssembly { get; set; }
[StringLength(512)]
public string AdminClass { get; set; }
[StringLength(32)]
public string ConfigName { get; set; }
public ProfileType SubType { get; set; }
[StringLength(256)]
public string ContainerType { get; set; }
[StringLength(256)]
public string SupportedFeatures { get; set; }

[InverseProperty(nameof(SetProfile.SetAPlugin))]
public virtual ICollection<SetProfile> SetAPlugins { get; set; }
[InverseProperty(nameof(SetProfile.SetBplugin))]
public virtual ICollection<SetProfile> SetBPlugins { get; set; }
[InverseProperty(nameof(SetProfile.SetCPlugin))]
public virtual ICollection<SetProfile> SetCPlugins { get; set; }
[InverseProperty(nameof(SetProfile.SetDPlugin))]
public virtual ICollection<SetProfile> SetDPlugins { get; set; }
[InverseProperty(nameof(SetProfile.SetEPlugin))]
public virtual ICollection<SetProfile> SetEPlugins { get; set; }
}
```

I've attached a screenshot of the DB columns from SSMS.
[image]

Comment: It seems that you have an incorrect mapping of table and your entity. It's hard to help without seeing the code

Comment: The code is not accurate: you mention Entity then Plugin.

Comment: What are ObjectStatus and PluginType, are they enums?

Comment: Yes, they are enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the SQL type is tinyint which is a Byte in code and which cannot be implicitly converted to enum. I used the following code to solve this:

```
        [Column("ObjectStatus")]
        public Byte objectStatus { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ObjectStatus ObjectStatus
        {
            get
            {
                if (objectStatus > 0)               
                    return (ObjectStatus)objectStatus;            
                else
                    return ObjectStatus.Active;
            }
            set
            {
                objectStatus = (Byte)value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is

```
public ObjectStatus ObjectStatus { get; set; }
```

& The enum must be created as follows:

```
public enum ObjectStatus : byte
{
    //List of values
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, I suggest decorating ObjectStatus property with 
[Column(TypeName = "tinyint")].
Being tinyint the implementation on database side, the byte strictness is required only when exchaning data with the database, not when using ObjectStatus enum type elsewhere.

Comment: You were in the right direction, the issue was indeed with the enum. However, inheriting it from byte doesn't provide the correct solution (at least not in my case). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping a property as `int` which should be a `byte` and only have one property mapped as `int`, which is `Serial`, so that should be the one.

Comment: No, Serial is int in the database. I will add a screenshot from SSMS.

Comment: My friend, this is the information that you supplied. From that, there is no other option. You didn't include the SetProfile, but because it is lazy loaded, I don't think the problem is there.